# How to inject services of dynamically created components

Tags: angular

```
export interface InfoPanelComponent {
    data: any;
}

export class ComplaintsComponent implements OnInit, InfoPanelComponent {
   data: any;             
   constructor(private navigationService: NavigationService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
   }

  onCancelClicked() {
      console.log(this.navigationService);
      this.navigationService.hidePanel(this.data.key, this.activatedRoute);
  }
}
```

The problem is, that `this.navigationService` is undefined. The service itself is provided in the `app.modules.ts` and can be injected in other components successfully.

I suppose the reason that it doesn't work is that the component above (and more components in future) is created dynamically:

```
private addPanel(item: InfoPanelItem, itemKey: string): void {
      const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(item.component);
      const viewContainerRef = this.infopanelHost.viewContainerRef;

      // create new component
      const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

      (<InfoPanelComponent>componentRef.instance).data = item.data;   
  }
```

I suppose that the services are not being injected because of that. Is there a way to generically inject all dependancies that the component requires? Note that the `ComplaintsComponent` is just one example and there are more to come, that may require different services.

Comment: If angular could not inject NavigationService you would get an error saying can't find provider for NavigationService. Can you show us where do you use `onCancelClicked` method?

Comment: I double yurzui s comment. I don't see why the dep. injection should fail here. Check if `NavigationService` is undefined in the ctor aswell

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can provide services to your *dynamic components* in these two ways. In my example I will demonstrate creating the component inside a container component, `DynamicContainerComponent`.

First in the container component import all the services you will need. In my example `AExampleService` and `BExampleService`.

**DynamicContainerComponent**

```
import {
  Component, ViewChild, AfterContentInit, ComponentFactoryResolver, Compiler, ViewContainerRef, NgModule, NgModuleRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AExampleService } from './services/AExampleService';
import { BExampleService } from './services/BExampleService';


@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-container',
  template: `<ng-container #vc></ng-container>`,
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-container.component.css']
})
export class DynamicContainerComponent implements AfterContentInit{
  @ViewChild('vc', { read: ViewContainerRef }) _container: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private aExampleService: AExampleService) { }

  ngAfterContentInit(){
    this.addDynamicComponent();
  }

  private addDynamicComponent(): void{...}
}
```

Now you can use the `AExampleService` and `BExampleService` by use of dependency injection in the *dynamic component*. This example shows two methods:

- Direct DI of the service `BExampleService` into the dynamic component
- Injecting the parent component `DynamicContainerComponent` into the *dynamic component* that will expose `AExampleService`.

Take a look at the code in `private addDynamicComponent(): void{...}`

**addDynamicComponent()**

```
private addDynamicComponent(): void{

  @Component({
    template: `<h2>This is a dynamic component</h2>`,
    styleUrls: ['./dynamic.component.css']
  })
  class DynamicComponent {
    constructor(
      public _parent: DynamicContainerComponent,
      private bExampleService: BExampleService) { }

    private someFunctionA(): void {
      this._parent.aExampleService.doSomthingA();
    }

    private someFunctionB(): void {
      this.bExampleService.doSomthingB();
    }
  }
  @NgModule({
    imports: [
      BrowserModule
    ],
    declarations: [DynamicComponent],
  }) class DynamicModule { }

  const mod = this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(DynamicModule);
  const factory = mod.componentFactories.find((comp) =>
    comp.componentType === DynamicComponent
  );

  this.cmpRef = this._container.createComponent(factory);
}
```

Notice that neither `AExampleService` or `BExampleService` were declared as providers of the *dynamic component*, but rather they are declared as providers to module that contains the `DynamicContainerComponent`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I will try out your method asap! Little question: I see you have defined the dynamic component inside a method. Since large parts of our application will be such components, and they will be large, this might end up rather messy. Is there a way to still define the components in a separate component file, and still inject the services?

Comment: In theory, you should be able to extract the composition of your dynamic component into say a generic service and use direct DI essentially the same way, but within the service instead of the container component. In fact, for the majority of what I do I use generic services to create "the guts" of each dynamic component. However, I still do the compilation of the dynamic component within a container component like the one demonstrated in the example. I am hesitant to give you a concrete yes (or no), because I personally have not done what I believe you're asking.

Comment: what if i want to inject a object as { provide: ActiveTab, useObject: tabData }, the tabData is data needed to be injected.

Comment: @Narm: is there a way to inject `private fb: FormBuilder` in the constructor of the dynamic component ? can you provide a Stackblidtz example ?